# Error when adding an option to an existing price set field

Tags: civievent, joomla, price-sets

Joomla 2.5.28
CiviCRM 4.7.14

I am working with a price set for an event. Most fields are radio or checkbox fields. When I go back to add another option to the field, CiviCRM throws a database error, but still saves the option.

Below is the error log corresponding with the error. Wondering if anyone else has seen this issue and if there is a fix OR if I need to submit an issue to JIRA.

```
Jan 05 17:54:39  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(229): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ; [nativecode=10...")
#4 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ; [nativecode=10...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ; [nativecode=10...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ; [nativecode=10...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#10 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;")
#12 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2438): DB_common->query("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;")
#13 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1627): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;")
#14 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(354): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;")
#15 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1297): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;", TRUE)
#16 /home/ipca/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup/otherSignupAdmin.php(198): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_signup WHERE price_option_id = ;")
#17 /home/ipca/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup/eventmembershipsignup.php(36): eventmembershipsignup_option_admin_postProcess(Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option))
#18 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(228): eventmembershipsignup_civicrm_postProcess("CRM_Price_Form_Option", Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option))
#19 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(151): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:5), "civicrm_postProcess", 2, "CRM_Price_Form_Option", Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#20 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/Joomla.php(100): CRM_Utils_Hook->commonInvoke(2, "CRM_Price_Form_Option", Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_postProcess", "joomla")
#21 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(403): CRM_Utils_Hook_Joomla->invoke(2, "CRM_Price_Form_Option", Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_postProcess")
#22 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(462): CRM_Utils_Hook::postProcess("CRM_Price_Form_Option", Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option))
#23 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(436): CRM_Core_Form->postProcessHook()
#24 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#25 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), "next", "Next")
#26 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), "next")
#27 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Price_Form_Option), "next")
#28 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#29 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/Page/Option.php(235): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#30 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/Page/Option.php(323): CRM_Price_Page_Option->edit(1)
#31 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Price_Page_Option->run((Array:5), NULL)
#32 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#33 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#34 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#35 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#36 /home/ipca/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(380): require_once("/home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php")
#37 /home/ipca/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(348): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/ipca/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php")
#38 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/includes/application.php(153): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#39 /home/ipca/public_html/administrator/index.php(46): JAdministrator->dispatch()
#40 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a core error as the table `civicrm_option_signup` where the DB error is thrown is a non-civi and maybe added through a custom code, extension etc. So you cannot raise an issue for this in JIRA.

From the backtrace, it looks like the error originated from an extension `com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup/otherSignupAdmin.php` at line 198 where the incomplete query is being written. Its recommended to ask your developer/maintainer of your site to track why the `price_option_id` is empty at that point.

Comment: Jitendra is right.  You may also try upgrading to the latest copy of this extension.  There are some recent-ish fixes that sound like they may address this very issue.